# How can I encode a getUserMedia stream into ilbc format in js?

Tags: javascript, audio, encoding, getusermedia

I would like to convert the getUserMedia stream into ilbc format, in my browser, before sending the information to a remote server.
Is there any js library for doing this?

Comment: @JaromandaX It is a fair programming question of, I guess, a JS developer. Why exactly it is off-topic?

Comment: `Is there any js library for doing this?` - that's why the question is off topic - not sure why my comment was removed, it was a fair point ... SO isn't a place to ask for libraries, that's what google is for

Comment: @JaromandaX I understand your point, but I did my own research before posting this question and couldn't find anything useful. Could use some help from the community with pointing to the right direction.

Comment: perhaps add some info into the question, like what is "ilbc" format, don't expect us to google for it when it looks like you're just asking for someone elses hard work (i.e a library) - chances are, you can't do that, unless you implement the codec in javascript, is that what you want?

Comment: do you know that Chrome WebRTC supports iLBC natively?